# pip - Не устанавливает пакеты (HTTPSConnectionPool [Errno 11002])

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Только недавно накатил новую ОС и вот, не могу поставить пакеты из пипа. Есть подозрение на две вещи - либо васянская сборка ОС либо то что все скачивается с `pythonhosted` а не с `PyPi`. В любом случае, как поправить это дело и скачивать все без всяких проблем. На всякий случай приложу все что выдал pip

```
Collecting requests
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021E79DAC3A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021E79DAC670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021E79DAC820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021E79DAC9D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021E79DACB80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021E79DACD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\trmas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: А просто в браузере `files.pythonhosted.org` открывается?

Comment: @andreymal только через впн, но с ним все также не качается через pip

Comment: Ну значит у вас проблемы с компьютером и/или интернет-провайдером какие-то

Comment: Проблема решена командой ```netsh Winsock reset```